# the usage of strtok() in c shows warnings and returns segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, string, char, strtok

I am learning C string operations and was using `strtok()` function. My code ended up with warning and then output was segmentation fault.

Here is the source code (in file **token3.c**):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char str[] = "aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.ff";
    char *p;
    p = strtok(str, '.');
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        p = strtok(NULL, '.');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Warnings during compilation:

```
token3.c: In function ‘main’:
token3.c:6:15: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strtok’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
      p=strtok(str,'.');
                   ^~~
In file included from token3.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:335:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
extern char *strtok (char *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __delim)
               ^~~~~~
token3.c:9:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strtok’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    p=strtok(NULL,'.');<br>
                  ^~~
In file included from token3.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:335:14: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’
but argument is of type ‘int’
    extern char *strtok (char *__restrict __s, const char *__restrict __delim)
                                               ^~~~~~<
```

expected output:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
```

actual output:

```
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

Comment: `strtok(str,'.');` --> replace with `strtok(str, ".")`

Comment: "argument 2 of ‘strtok’ makes pointer from
integer": argument 2 is `'.'`, the char is silently converted to `int` and then with a warning to `char*`. But calling `strtok()` on a string constant also makes me shiver.

Comment: @HenkHolterman -- makes you shiver because you dislike `strtok`? Or for some other reason? OP is not calling on a `const char *`, but rather on an allocated buffer.

Comment: You're right, i misread the `[]` .

Comment: @HenkHolterman, FWIW, `strtok` makes me shiver in general though ... ;)

Comment: First, the posted code does not compile.  Why? because it should be: `#include` not `include`

Comment: @user3629249 sorry my bad... Forget to correct it while posting the question

Comment: This is the reason why you should not make up some random lines of code for the question but simply use copy&paste of real code that causes the problem. There is nothing you can forget and no typos if you use c&p.

Comment: Lesson learned: Take the compiler's warnings serious. Fix the related code.

Answer (score 3):

That's was a mistake just replace

```
strtok(str,'.');
```

with

```
strtok(str,".");
```

The 2nd argument of strtok() is denotes the delimiters and expects the type

> const char *

and so must be enclosed in " ".

Syntax of strtok()

> char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);

Answer (score 3):

the syntax for `strtok()` is:

```
char *strtok( char *str, const char *delim );
```

Notice that the second parameter is a char pointer, not a char, so the second parameter in each of the calls to `strtok()` should be wrapped in double quotes, not single quotes

After correcting the syntax and adding some spacing for readability, the resulting code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main( void ) 
{
    char str[] = "aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.ff";
    char *p;
    p = strtok( str, "." );

    while( p ) 
    {
        printf( "%s\n", p );
        p = strtok( NULL, "." );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and when running the corrected source code, the output is:

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
ee
ff
```

Note: with modern C compilers, the statement:

```
return 0;
```

can be eliminated as a return from `main()` (when not specifically stated otherwise) is 0

Comment: Interesting the *"space within the quote"* formatting. I've always preferred the *"space before"* approach, e.g. `p = strtok (NULL, ".");` Nothing wrong with your approach, clear and readable. Also C99 introduced the default of `return 0;` if excluded.